# Series of ones and zeros

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I got this task "How many series are there of length 10 with values {0,1} that have at least one "110" configuration?"
It says i should use the inclusion-exclusion pattern, but I don't know how. Any help would be nice

Comment: If you are told the series starts with $110$ how many possibilities?  If you are told it ends with $110$ how many possibilities?  If you just add those together, note that $110xxxx110$ gets counted twice, so you will need to subtract it.  How many places can $110$ start?  How many ways to have two of them?  Three of them?